# How to avoid daily collation of excel file

Tags: python-3.x

I receive similar csv data (same number of same columns) on daily basis. I have prepared the code to collate them in one excel file. But I have to run it on daily basis for each new file received everyday. Is there a way to just pick the new received file and append it with the collated file.

the name of the files is similar except it contains daily date which differentiates the files.

My code is working fine, it's just that when I run, it'll read all the files and collate them again. While what I want is it reads the new file received everyday and collate it with previous day's collated file.

Comment: Hello! If you were able to provide relevant parts of your original code, there might be a simpler way to improve it and address the second part of your question